# null values in mysqli parameters

Tags: php, mysqli, null

my mysql table accepts NULL values on many fields, I'm updating records and my desktop app is creating a http string as follows and sending to a php script.

```
www.webpage/script.php?firstval=48.345345&secondval=234&thirdval=&fourthval=simon
```

on the db thirdval is already NULL
but the parameters in the http string may or may not hold values

do I need to :
A)pass the parameter in the http string as  
b)pass the parameter in the httpstring as 
c)cater for the null value in the php script( 
d)not include the parameter in the http string at all
or something else
my phpscript is like so :

```
 ?php

DEFINE ('DBUSER', 'generic01');
DEFINE ('DBPW', 'genpass');
DEFINE ('DBHOST', 'mysql4.xxxxxxxxx.com'); 
DEFINE ('DBNAME', '_Places');


$dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW);
if (!$dbc) {
die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
exit();
}

$dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbc, DBNAME);
if (!$dbs) {
die(" Database selection bit failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
exit();
}
$lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['lat']);
$lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['lng']);
$prox = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['prox']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['description']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['id']);
$direction = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['direction']);
$avoiddays = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['avoiddays']);
$validfrom = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['validfrom']);
$validto = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['validto']);
$gefid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['gefid']);
$expiry = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['expiry']);


$query = "UPDATE places SET rt_lat = '$lat',rt_lng= '$lng',rt_prox = '$prox', rt_description = '$description', rt_direction = '$direction',rt_avoiddays = '$avoiddays',rt_validto = '$validto',rt_validfrom = '$validfrom',rt_gefid = '$gefid',rt_expiry='$expiry' WHERE rt_id = '$id'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Query MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));


mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

All help appreciated,

Comment: If the field is set to accept nulls, it will be written as a null unless you provide a value to it.  This happens automatically.

Comment: ^ That would require quite a bit of rewrite to the query itself though as you'd have to drop entire field assignments out rather than assigning them to `NULL`

Comment: CD001 , yes that's the issue, I would have to manipulate the http string to include or exclude the assignment which may or may not require the '&' on the back of the final parameter.

Comment: I have modified my desktop app to not include the parameters if their value is nothing, actually even if the http string contains the parameter or not I get '0' values, not NULL values, even with the php script including Marc B's bit below. so I guess I need to modify it so that only the non NULL fields are used in the insert? I have no idea how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to include it in the http request, but you have to catch that, otherwise you get an E_NOTICE error.

For all fields that can be null:

```
if (isset($_GET['gefid'])) {
  $gefid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['gefid']);
} else {
  $gefid = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has no knowledge of SQL nulls. If you want a blank/not-set $_GET value to become a null in the DB, then you have to take special steps:

```
if(isset($_GET['lat']) || ($_GET['lat'] == '')) {
   $lat = 'NULL'; // a plain PHP string with the word "null" in it
} else {
   $lat = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['lat']) . "'"; // note the extra quotes
}

$sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ($lat, ....)"
```

If you do it any other way, e.g (just as an example, yes it's sql-injection vulnerable):

```
$sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ('$_GET[lat]', ...)";
```

Then for an empty `$_GET['lat']` your query would actually be

```
INSERT ... VALUES ('', ...)
```

and you'd be inserting an empty string, NOT an sql null.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I have just written the code to only add the assignments if their length is greater than 0, it now only sends valid assignmments BUT despite having added if(isset($_GET['gefid']) || ($_GET['gefid'] == '')) {
   $gefid = 'NULL'; // a plain PHP string with the word "null" in it
} else {
   $gefid = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['gefid']) . "'"; // note the extra quotes
}  the database shows 0 instead of NULL. Yet there are other older rows that contain NULL values in the same field ?